# Create new sheets based on roster and auto calculate completes

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, Im setting up a spreadsheet that will track employee progress. Im new to vba and macro programming in excel but am not foreign to programing in general. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. What I want to do is as follows.

Start off with 3 sheets (roster, log, Total) The log sheet will have all the tracking metrics of each employee.Total will Total each employees log sheet together and roster will be a dynamic employee list. As a new entry is created in roster then I want to copy the log sheet and rename it by the name put into roster and add the new (named) sheet into the Totals calculations.

For arguments sake just say that each log sheet only has a numerical value in a1 and total is just tallying all log sheets a1 fields. Roster contains just a first name in column A and no other data. (Given direction I should be able to expand the concept to a more intricate set of  sheets.

Additionally it would be interesting to be able to remove a name from roster and have the said log sheet be deleted and removed from the totals formula... :D

Again Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Maintaining referential integrity between sheets in Excel can be done, but it's a pain. As a first project I suggest you to start with a fixed number of sheets (3). One for roster, one for log (with different rows or cols per employee, and one for the totals. The last one is not really necessary since you should calculate the totals in the second one. Start with something like this, then move on to your schema if needed. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people try to make excel work like a database and it is ultimately doomed to failure. As this is a green field project I would start it right and use some sort of database. The choice is yours depending on your skillset, hardware available and what it will be used for. A good starting point would be good old MS Access, it is quick to learn and in the right hands very powerful. If it is going to be higher use then maybe look to a server based data store such as SQL server and write the front end in anything you want (Access, vb.net, asp.net etc)

The point here is choosing the right tool for the right job, spreadsheets have their place but databases they are not